# How do I break a long String in c# without breaking a words

Tags: c#

I want to break a long String in c# without breaking a words
Example: `S AAA BBBBBBB CC DDDDDD V`        Breaking Character on 7 Count:

```
S AAA
BBBBBBB
CC 
DDDDDD 
V
```

How do I do this?

Comment: By what criteria should you select `S AAA` as a word?

Comment: why so many c# versions specified? you want response for each one separately?

Comment: I don't see a pattern here. when you say "breaking characters on 7 count", you'll never get the result you're aiming for. For example if you break the first word on a 7 char count you'll be getting `"S AAA  B"` not `"S AAA  "` also `"CC"` does not correspond to your rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick if I've understood your question correctly. A recursive implementation would have been cooler, but tail recursion is too damn bad in C# :)

Could also be implemented with yield and `IEnumerable<string>`.

```
string[] splitSpecial(string words, int lenght)
{
  // The new result, will be turned into string[]
  var newSplit = new List<string>();
  // Split on normal chars, ie newline, space etc
  var splitted = words.Split();
  // Start out with null
  string word = null;

  for (int i = 0; i < splitted.Length; i++)
  {
      // If first word, add
      if (word == null)
      {
          word = splitted[i];
      }
      // If too long, add
      else if (splitted[i].Length + 1 + word.Length > lenght)
      {
          newSplit.Add(word);
          word = splitted[i];
      }
      // Else, concatenate and go again
      else
      {
          word += " " + splitted[i];
      }
  }
  // Flush what we have left, ie the last word
  newSplit.Add(word);

  // Convert into string[] (a requirement?)
  return newSplit.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
string inputStr = "S AAA BBBBBBB CC DDDDDD V ";
int maxWordLength = 7;
char separator = ' ';

string[] splitted = inputStr.Split(new[]{separator}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var joined = new Stack<string>();
joined.Push(splitted[0]);

foreach (var str in splitted.Skip(1))
{
    var strFromStack = joined.Pop();
    var joindedStr = strFromStack + separator + str;
    if(joindedStr.Length > maxWordLength)
    {
        joined.Push(strFromStack);
        joined.Push(str);
    }
    else
    {
        joined.Push(joindedStr);
    }
}   
var result = joined.Reverse().ToArray();

Console.WriteLine ("number of words: {0}", result.Length);

Console.WriteLine( string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result) );
```

prints:

```
number of words: 5
S AAA
BBBBBBB
CC
DDDDDD
V
```

Comment: This isn't the output that the OP wants. The first "word" should be `S AAA`.

Comment: @ChrisF @anurag In question there is a statement `without breaking a words`. Is `S AAA` a word?

Comment: I might be wrong, but from what i understand from his question and expected output, he wants to split the string by space character and then if consecutive words have less than 7 characters combined, then they should be taken as a single token. Hence the "S AAA" token.

Comment: @mematei *split the string by space* wht then `S AAA` is a word?

Comment: @Ilya Ivanov Please read the entire comment, i'll emphasize the part you need to look over "if consecutive words have less than 7 characters combined, then they should be taken as a single token", this i made out from the "Breaking Character on 7 Count"

Comment: @Ilya Ivanov i do not want to break my string by space..i want to break my string by count 7 and also check No Breaked word is print

Comment: @anurag by any chance do you have a certainty that words will be separated by only one space? or can there be multiple spaces between words, and do you wish to preserve them? furthermore, if a word is longer than 7 characters, it should be treated as a single token?

Comment: he wants soemthing like split text in lines, where each line is max 7 chars long (or word length if it is more then 7)

Comment: @sasjaq  yes you understand my need

Comment: @mematei I've updated my answer to meets this needs. Thank you for comments and explanations.

Comment: static public void splitter()
{ string input = "My Name is pradeep singh currently i am working with xyz pvt Ltd ";  int lineSize = 10; int lineCounter = 0;
StringBuilder stringBuilders = new StringBuilder();
string[] inputArr = input.Split(); for (int n = 0; n < inputArr.Length; n++) { if (inputArr[n].Length > (lineSize - lineCounter)) {  stringBuilders.Append(' ');
stringBuilders.Append("\n"); lineCounter = 0; }
stringBuilders.Append(inputArr[n]); stringBuilders.Append(' ');
lineCounter = lineCounter + inputArr[n].Length + 1; }
MessageBox.Show(stringBuilders.ToString()); }}

Answer (score 3):

Here's a shorter solution harnessing the power of regular expressions.

```
string input = "S AAA BBBBBBB CC DDDDDD V";

// Match up to 7 characters with optional trailing whitespace, but only on word boundaries
string pattern = @"\b.{1,7}\s*\b";

var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

foreach (var match in matches)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(match.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not to try regex?

```
(?:^|\s)(?:(.{1,7}|\S{7,}))(?=\s|$)
```

and use all captures.

C# code:

```
var text = "S AAA BBBBBBB CC DDDDDD V";
var matches = new Regex(@"(?:^|\s)(?:(.{1,7}|\S{7,}))(?=\s|$)").Matches(text).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value).ToArray();
foreach (var match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

Output:

```
S AAA
BBBBBBB
CC
DDDDDD
V
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        string str = "S AAA BBBBBBB CC DDDDDD V";
        var words = str.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (sb.Length == 0)
            {
                sb.Append(words[i]);
            }
            else if (sb.Length + words[i].Length < 7)
            {
                sb.Append(' ');
                sb.Append(words[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                result.Add(sb.ToString());
                sb.Clear();
                sb.Append(words[i]);
            }
        }
        if (sb.Length > 0)
        {
            result.Add(sb.ToString());
        }
```

Results will contain:

```
S AAA
BBBBBBB
CC
DDDDDD
V
```

The predicate can be adjusted depending on if the separator between words should be included in the 7 characters or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to add row break to HTML text:

SplitLongText(string _SourceText, int _MaxRowLength) 
        {

```
        if (_SourceText.Length < _MaxRowLength)
        {
            return _SourceText;
        }
        else 
        {
            string _RowBreakText="";
            int _CurrentPlace = 0;
            while (_CurrentPlace < _SourceText.Length)
            {
                if (_SourceText.Length - _CurrentPlace < _MaxRowLength)
                {
                    _RowBreakText += _SourceText.Substring(_CurrentPlace);
                    _CurrentPlace = _SourceText.Length; 

                }
                else
                {
                    string _PartString = _SourceText.Substring(_CurrentPlace, _MaxRowLength);
                    int _LastSpace = _PartString.LastIndexOf(" ");
                    if (_LastSpace > 0)
                    {
                        _RowBreakText += _PartString.Substring(0, _LastSpace) + "<br/>" + _PartString.Substring(_LastSpace, (_PartString.Length - _LastSpace));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _RowBreakText += _PartString + "<br/>";
                    }
                    _CurrentPlace += _MaxRowLength;
                }

            }
            return _RowBreakText;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**2021**

Look at this extension method, it uses recursivity

```
public static string SubstringDontBreakWords(this string str, int maxLength)
{
    return str.Length <= maxLength ? str : str.Substring(0, str.LastIndexOf(" ")).Trim().SubstringDontBreakWords(maxLength);
}
```

Use it like this

```
string text = "Hello friends";
text.SubstringDontBreakWords(10)
```